# My HDD is NOT logically visible in enclosure (portable HDD setup), but IS hardware-visible

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery, password-protection, portable-harddrive

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 320 running Windows 10 and am using it to attempt to solve this issue.

I have a physically undamaged 2.5 inch HDD (ST1000LM024 5400RPM 1000GB), I took it out of a broken Lenovo G50-80 laptop, which went suddenly dead.
I did set a password for it, in the BIOS. I'm beginning to suspect this might be the problem.

On the drive itself it says the input is 5 volts and 0.85 ampere (**+0.5V 0.85A**) but the enclosure requires 12V and 2A, which might apply to only 3,5 inch drives, and not apply to 2,5 inch drive, I don't know.

**Sub question**: *If the BIOS password is the problem, would my only option be to try to repair the old laptop, or would sticking it in a similar laptop allow me to remove the password as well?*

```
HDD-Specifications:
Samsung Spinpoint M8 ST1000LM024
1TB / 5400 RPM 8MB Cache / 2.5" SATA / 3.0Gb/s
Item Dimensions:    3.95 x 2.75 x 0.37 in
Item Weight:    3.77 ounces
Size:   1 TB
```

But when I stick it in an enclosure, so as to use it as an external hard drive, Windows doesn't show it in Windows Explorer. When I open the *Windows Disk Management* software [{DISKMGMT.MSC: **Disk 1**, 931GB} (see pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWuHS.jpg), it is visible. It is also visible under  [**{Control Panel >> All Control Panel Items >> Devices and Printers} (see pic)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT9sq.jpg)  .

It's almost as if it is visible physically (on a hardware level), but not  logically (on a software level). I saw some popup dialog boxes that asked to  [{initialize} (see pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuKIU.jpg) (is that formatting?) this drive. Of course I refused to do that, it contains a lot of data I need to keep, for work and personal stuff that has no backups.

***Question***: How do I make this drive visible again, so that I can use it as an external hard drive?

I checked, but no other question here was similar **enough** to my question. That could be all me, true.

[image: Properties-Events]

Information under Properties-Events tab:

```
 Device USBSTOR\Disk&Ven_ASMedia&Prod_AS2105&Rev_0\00000000000000000000&0 
    was not migrated due to partial or ambiguous match.
    Last Device Instance Id: USBSTOR\Disk&Ven_&Prod_USB_DISK_2.0&Rev_PMAP\070724BE0D3EF164&0
    Class Guid: {4D36E967-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
    Location Path: 
    Migration Rank: 0xF000FC000000F120
    Present: false
    Status: 0xC0000719
```

[image: Properties-General tab]

Comment: In Disk manager, it says 'unallocated', so there is no drive letter associated to the disk, and it will not appear in explorer. Can you right-click on the disk --> and allocate a drive letter? (something like: 'change drive letter and path')

Comment: Some Lenovos use 'Full Disk Encryption', see here: [link](https://support.lenovo.com/ch/en/solutions/migr-69621). Try to find out if that is the case. You might try the Lenovo forum to find out how to access your disk.

Comment: no, i can not. Only options when I right click are Properties and Help. See screenshots of that above, the  Properties-General tab and the  Properties-Events tab

Comment: Thinking about it, the problem could lie with the harddisk-enclosure you are using: sometimes they are not able to handle disks which have a MBR, I once had a similar problem. Try to use a "SATA to USB Connector", as they are provided in SSD migration kits. (I used the connector provided with a Samsung SSD starter kit to access my old hard drive).

Comment: Matching the proper driver failed, I would try a different enclosure, evidently Windows 10 does not have the proper driver for the ASMedia enclosure.....http://www.thewindowsclub.com/device-not-migrated-windows

Comment: @MOAB But if Windows had not had the proper driver for ASmedia, it wouldn't have recognized it as ASMedia, right? Besides, I a different enclosure, with the same result, zippety doodah.

Comment: There is more than one asmedia chip, each has a different driver. Have no clue what is going on.

Comment: Please take our [tour] to learn how we indicate solved problems.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: It  was the password.

**Long answer**: I stuck the HDD in a Dell Inspiron 1545 laptop, which is so old, it's HDD is still NTFS/MBR formatted. It asked me for the password (interestingly, when I typed it in, it didn't even show asterixes).

I typed that in and it did't give an error message, but it got stuck: it went to a black screen with a blinking cursor (underscore).

I repeated that, but the only option left was to go into the Dell's BIOS and change the password. Same result: no boot. I repeated but now I erased the password. I expected it to boot up, but it still froze on the black screen with a blinking cursor. I guess that's because it was a GPT formatting?
I attached the HDD via a Maiwo K306 enclosure to the Ideapad, and ipso presto, that worked. Also works on the AS2105 enclosure.

(Before, to test my two enclosures, I tried to hook them up with the Dells HDD which didn't have a password, but which produced no joy whatsoever. At this point I thought I was going nuts, because it seemed that the HDD password was NOT problem)

Comment: sorry, I don;t get why i should not tag it SOLVED. Also, can you explain your last sentence.